# Exclude 2 entries from a query

Tags: craft3, entry, query

I know this question has been asked before but I'm still not able to solve the issue in this particular situation.
I want to remove one fixed(#95) entry id and the current entry.id from the query.

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('section').level(1).id('and, not ~ entry.id, not 95').all() %}
```

The result being only the fixed (#95) entry.id is removed from the query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('section').level(1).id(['not', entry.id, 95]).all() %}
```